# How do I modify a response's ReadOnlyHttpHeaders in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, http-headers

RestTemplate.exchange is returning a ResponseEntity with ReadOnlyHttpHeaders. I want to add/modify these headers but since it is read only how do I do that?

Comment: post your code, what headers, and how far you have gotten.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[HttpHeaders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html) implements [MultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html), you can create a new mutable `HttpHeaders` including `ReadOnlyHttpHeaders` and modify:

```java
        HttpHeaders readOnlyHttpHeaders = ...

        HttpHeaders mutableHttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(readOnlyHttpHeaders);
        mutableHttpHeaders.put("foo", List.of("bar"));
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the latest Spring version at the time of writing this (5.2.6). The constructor simply stores a reference to the `ReadOnlyHttpHeaders` instance passed in and delegates all operations to it, which all throw an exception (because it's read only, of course).

Answer (score 18):

In case of above answer did not work for you, try below

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(httpEntity.getHeaders());
```

Comment: It works for me, thanks !
I noticed that the headers in the actual httpEntity are updated when httpHeaders is updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("key", new String[] {"value"}).build();

ServerWebExchange mutatedExchange = exchange.mutate().request(request).build();
```

And the mutatedExchange  will have a header with the new key: value pair.

Comment: I think this answer is for webClient and not for restTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Make writeable header instance and use it:

```
HttpHeaders writableHeaders = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(headers);
writableHeaders.put(authHeader, List.of(OBFUSCATED_VALUE));
```